# Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) con el logger SLF4J en jboss/wildfly 10 se borra

Tags: java, wildfly, logger, slf4j

Configuré mi aplicación web para usar un MDC de esta manera:

```
    MDC.put("cliente", "TEST");
    org.slf4j.MDC.put("cliente2", "TEST2");
```

Dentro de la clase de inicio para el servicio REST **javax.ws.rs.core.Application**

```
import org.jboss.logging.MDC;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationResource extends Application {

    public ApplicationResource(){
        MDC.put("cliente", "TEST");
        org.slf4j.MDC.put("cliente2", "TEST2");
    }
```

Y el resultado de la aplicacion en el registro fue:

```
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,048 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,115 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.mypackage.providers.ObjectMapperContextResolver from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.mypackage.PronetResource from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.mypackage.ResourceOne from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.mypackage.ResourceTwo from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,116 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class com.mypackage.mappers.ExceptionMapper from Application class com.mypackage.ApplicationResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
[TEST] [TEST2] 21:18:25,227 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /api/test
[] [] 21:18:25,292 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "api-test-web" (runtime-name : "api-test-web.war")
[2018-03-01 09:18:25,311] Artifact api-test-web:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-03-01 09:18:25,311] Artifact api-test-web:war exploded: Deploy took 13,992 milliseconds
[] [] 21:18:31,004 INFO  [com.mypackage.TestApiImpl] (default task-1) Consulting... --> Request: QueryRequest(tipo_documento=CI, documento=5789124)
[] [] 21:18:31,173 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[] [] 21:18:31,605 INFO  [com.mypackage.TestApiImpl] (default task-1) End consulting --> Response: QueryResponse(datos=[])
[] [] 21:28:44,315 INFO  [com.mypackage.TestApiImpl] (default task-2) Consulting... --> Request: QueryRequest(tipo_documento=CI, documento=4199210)
[] [] 21:28:44,332 INFO  [com.mypackage.TestApiImpl] (default task-2) End consulting --> Response: QueryResponse(data=[])
```

¿Por qué el MDC que inicialicé se borra? ¿Es necesario que lo declare en algún otro lugar?

Answer (score -1):

Establezca el valor MDC en la implementación real del método RS - establezca el valor al principio y elimine el valor al final del método.

También puede escribir un Interceptor para que pueda manejar fácilmente todas las llamadas RS:

```
@Interceptors({ WsRestApiInterceptor.class })
public class SomeRsImpl ...

..
public class WsRestApiInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        MDC.put("key", "value");
        invocationContext.proceed()
        MDC.remove("key");
...
```